# Can i use/query my local sql database server for Windows Azure cloud service developed in WCF Web Server?

Tags: wcf, web-services, azure, cloud

I am using Windows Azure for deploying my web services.I want to know can i query my local SQL database server from Windows Azure Cloud Service made in WCF Web Role?

If yes...can you please tell me some tutorial or useful link related with that.

Thanks And Regards
Rachit Arora

Comment: Sounds like you want service bus relay http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-relay/

Answer (score 0):

The [Access on-premises data via Azure Service Bus sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/CSAzureServiceBusWCFDS-d69e2ae0#content) on the [Windows Azure Code Samples site](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/CSAzureServiceBusWCFDS-d69e2ae0#content) is just what you're looking for.